# Image upload using Ext js is not working in IE but working in chrome

Tags: image, upload

I am getting response content type as application/json which is causing problem in IE11 but not in chrome.

Comment: Please provide more info or some code.

Comment: here is the code:uploadPhoto: function(record) { var uploadPanel = this.down('ihg-picture-upload-panel'),pictureLoadForm = uploadPanel.down('ihg-picture-upload-form'),field = pictureLoadForm.down('fileuploadfield'),valid = (!Ext.isEmpty(field.value) && uploadPanel.pendingAction === 'UPDATE') || (uploadPanel.pendingAction === 'DELETE');if (valid && uploadPanel.pendingAction === 'UPDATE'){ uploadPanel.doCreatePicture(this.afterUploadPhoto, this, record);}
if (uploadPanel.pendingAction === 'DELETE') {
 uploadPanel.doDeletePicture(this.afterUploadPhoto, this);
  }     return valid; },

Comment: afterUploadPhoto: function(success, message, recordId) {
if (success) {
 this.showSuccessMsg(recordId);
} else {   this.showPictureUploadFailMsg();  },

Comment: I am getting error in console as unable to decode the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your content type header to text/plain. This link explains more https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload. You can also see what their example does http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#form-fileuploads